# Visual Studio Online / VSTS deleted user

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

A few days ago a deleted a user from my VSTS account on :

https://foo.visualstudio.com/_user

Today when I tried to check some shelvets from this guy I realized that those were also gone.

Is there any way to recover a deleted user?

I can't find any information online about it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The Shelves won't be deleted if the user has been removed from VSTS account. Can you reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes basically it's just a matter of removing the user and then when you try to search for shelvets using the user name on Team explorer, you will that nothing is shown. However as the below user replied adding back the user enables me to find the branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the user back on that same link : https://foo.visualstudio.com/_user

The shelvesets will be there.